# What's wrong with this snippet of VBA code?

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
 If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox1.Text = "False" Then
        msgbox("Filename invalid. Try again.",vbOKOnly)
```

I'm getting "Compiler Error: Expected: =" error message.

Comment: I have never used VBA, but I would guess you want `==`.

Comment: @jordanm: No. Visual Basic is sane and the correct comparison operator is `=` ;)

Comment: @jordanm: Pretty sure it's `=`. `==` is used in C++ variant languages if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's because you can only call `Sub`s either with `Call` or without parentheses in VBA. So change it to:

```
MsgBox "Filename invalid. Try again.", vbOKOnly
```

Or, if you like this style better:

```
Call MsgBox("Filename invalid. Try again.", vbOKOnly)
```

(And the reason you get the error is because it expects you to assign the result to a variable, hence it expects an `=`.)